# Norton Security blocked "Fake Tech Support Website" within router?

Tags: network, router, intrusion

Norton Security (software installed on the computer) supposedly blocked a fake website coming from my internet router.

(See the full alert details window screenshot).

[image]

My internet router is a [BT Home Hub 5](https://www.trustedreviews.com/reviews/bt-home-hub-5) and the IP address http://192.168.1.254 is the router's IP address and [UDP port 53 seems to be the DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports).  All other devices (computers, smartphones, tablets etc.) connected to the network are assigned different IP addresses.

Is there something in the router which may be attempting to compromise security?

Answer (score 2):

The description is likely misleading and confusing.

Looking for this kind of problem on the internet suggests that a response to a DNS request originating from your local system was blocked, since the content of the response suggested that you've tried to visit some "Fake Tech Support Site". This might not have been a deliberate choice by you but might implicitly originate from some advertisement included in a page you've visited.

Your system is likely configured to use the router as DNS server (common setup). That's why the response to the DNS query comes also from your router. But it is not that your router is attacking your system, all it does is respond to the DNS query you've send. Only that the contents of the response indicates that your browser tried to access some malicious site.